# Idiom "Do the best"

Tags: meaning, idioms, usage, phrases

Does the second sentence mean the same as the first one?

> They are doing ***all possible*** to further the passage of the Senate.
>
> They are ***doing the best*** to facilitate the passage of the Senate.

Comment: The expression is _doing their best_.

Comment: What @Kate said. And the other (semantically identical) expression is *doing **everything** possible*, not ***all***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica but why "all" doesn't work?

Comment: There is nothing syntactically wrong with *doing **all** possible* as opposed to *doing **everything** possible*. However, it's simply not said and sounds odd. It's just a quirk of the language that we use. There is no rational explanation for why *all* is odd, aside from the fact that it's not normally used.

Comment: That aside, the two do not mean the same thing. Among *all possible* could be mediocre or poor things—but *the best* (or more idiomatically ***their*** *best*) would exclude those things.